# Possible to print out all the SharePoint List's column in a page

Tags: column, printing

Currently, I have to go to each List inside the SharePoint 2007 Site and use the Snipping Tools to copy the column information as shown below

[image]

**The Question**

Is there ways that I can copy all the column information for all the List in a SharePoint 2007 Site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a webpart or an application page

Or you can run the following in PowerShell on the server:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$s = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("http://sharepoint")
$w = $s.OpenWeb()
$w.Lists | 
 Where-Object {!$_.Hidden} | 
 Select-Object @{Label="List";Expression={$_.Title}} -ExpandProperty Fields |
 Where-Object {!$_.Hidden} | 
 Sort-Object List, Title |
 Format-Table Title, Type, Required -GroupBy List > Fields.txt
$w.Dispose()
$s.Dispose()
```

This will put Title and Type of each non hidden field of each non hidden list into fields.txt from the site `http://sharepoint`

For PowerShell version 1:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$s = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("http://sharepoint")
$w = $s.OpenWeb()
$w.Lists | 
 Where-Object {!$_.Hidden} | 
 Select-Object @{name="List";Expression={$_.Title}} -ExpandProperty Fields |
 Where-Object {!$_.Hidden} | 
 Sort-Object List, Title |
 Format-Table Title, Type, Required -GroupBy List > Fields.txt
$w.Dispose()
$s.Dispose()
```

Comment: +1 That's a good script. However, may I know how I can include the 'Type' and the 'Required' into the Fields.txt? Also, I have include a script for PowerShell ver 1 since I do not have the latest Powershell.

Comment: The type should already be there and you can just add `, Required` to the Format-Table

Comment: Thanks Jakobsen. I notice that when I maximize my notepad to open the Fields.txt, I am able to view the column 'Type'. (It was far align to the right. Also, I have update both script to include the 'Required' field.